# Linux: How to change command to different path?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed nodejs on my ubuntu system. The command `which nodejs`gives me the following response: `/usr/bin/nodejs` which is correct because a `nodejs -v` gives me the version I installed, 0.10.25.

If I type `which node` instead, I get `/usr/sbin/node` which does nothing at all.

My question is now: How do I change the command `node` to `/usr/sbin/nodejs` so that I have a working installation for all the programs which rely on the command `node`?

**Short:** How do I execute `/usr/bin/nodejs` if I run `node` from the console?

Thanks in advance,
F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .bashrc file, create an alias thus:

`alias nodejs='/usr/bin/nodejs'`

Don't add whitespaces otherwise they'll be counted. Another solution is to consider adding `/usr/bin` to your PATH. Know that `/usr/sbin` is parsed first, before `/usr/bin/` but it's not wise to swap round these two locations because in the event duplicate commands are available (as in your case) it can lead to unknown behaviour. So creating an alias is a safer solution.

EDIT: To bring your .bashrc file changes into effect, execute:

`source .bashrc`

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer because I think it's very important mentioning the side effects and I like the solution with the alias.

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH variable

```
echo $PATH
```

Make sure /usr/bin is in front of /usr/sbin/

i.e. `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH`

Comment: PATH is one of the most commonly used environment variables. Usually people customize it in ~/.bashrc, so you don't have to specify it every time.